# How can I stay same page when I refresh web page on React?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I deployed web application through AWS.
After I log in web page, I can see main page.
And then, I refresh the page. After that, It is redirected login page. It is not keeping login state.
I already checked s3 bucket's static web site hosting. Error page is set index.html. Also I have tried to create custom error response on Cloud Front. But it doesn't work.
I can see error in headers like below.

```
x-amz-error-code : NoSuchKey
x-amz-error-detail-key: mypage
x-amz-error-message: The specified key does not exist.
x-cache: Error from cloudfront
```